# Git-Overleaf push changes to Github

Tags: git, github, overleaf

When I follow the Overleaf tutorial "Creating an Overleaf project from an existing Git repository"

```
$ cd my-paper
$ git remote add overleaf https://git.overleaf.com/5b98bfbf54474d00010421b1
$ git checkout master
$ git pull overleaf master --allow-unrelated-histories
$ git revert --mainline 1 HEAD
$ git push overleaf master
```

When I do changes and then push

```
info: detecting host provider for 'https://git.overleaf.com/'...
info: detecting host provider for 'https://git.overleaf.com/'...
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 245 bytes | 245.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)
To https://git.overleaf.com/640569171e2944e09c7b2e5f
   d0761a5..6f589fd  master -> master
```

**The overleaf gets updated, but the Github NO**

How can I push changes to both?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that on GitHub I was on the main branch, and on Overleaf in the master.

I solved the issue by pushing the master branch to github

`git push -u origin master`